# Скопировать страницу

Tags: html, wordpress

Прошу прощения сразу, вопрос наверно банальный, но к сожалению не для меня.
Есть сайт на ворпресе. Нужно в него вставить страницу, почти точную копию "https://conteshop.com.ua/sizes". Я имею в виду размеры, без шапки.
Как это осуществить? Обратите внимание пожалуйста, в размерах лифчиков, там есть форма, я так понял на ajax.

Comment: Разъясните подробнее, пожалуйста. Ваш вопрос непонятен. Вы хотите создать в вордпрессе копию этой страницы?

Comment: Уже даже создал, копировав HTML код таблиц, в созданные спойлеры. Но самый главный вопрос остался. Там есть форма, не знаю на чем она написана,  разделе ""Размерная таблица бюстгалтеры", ее я тоже скопировал, но вот только она у меня не работает.